# Google not indexing my npmjs package - how to fix it?

Tags: npm

I've published [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lucien144/vue3-parallaxy) few months ago and the package is still [not indexed by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue3-parallaxy&sca_esv=575710480&sxsrf=AM9HkKkX_UfKZTR-Qz7ueFS3ObZSRGZfJg%3A1698044629260&ei=1Ro2ZYzBD5OI4dUPq5K4iAg&ved=0ahUKEwjM_8GXzYuCAxUTRLgEHSsJDoEQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=vue3-parallaxy&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiDnZ1ZTMtcGFyYWxsYXh5MgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADMgoQABhHGNYEGLADSPkMUPsKWPsKcAF4AZABAJgBAKABAKoBALgBA8gBAPgBAeIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgg&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1).

I checked NPMJS' `robots.txt` to see if they block `@user` packages or if there's not `robots` metatag in the page's header but no luck. Really not sure what's going on here...

Comment: It's indexed now?